# How to not reinstall packages when installing a bunch of package?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, cloning

I saved the `pacman -Qqe` output from a previous arch install and now I'm using this list to install all the packages I had at once. However some of them are already installed and it wants to reinstall them which I fear will break things. Is there a pacman parameter to ignore the packages that are already installed? Or at least not to reinstall them but just update.

Comment: Reinstalling is not a problem: pacman simply recognises that you have an up-to-date version of the package and tells you this.

Comment: @jasonwryan reinstalling some package generates locale again, rerun mkinitcpio etc it's annoying I'm looking for a way to skip the reinstalls when installing in bulk

Comment: What is the command you're using ? When using `pacman` with `-S` or `-U` you can add `--needed` to skip reinstalling up to date packages. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @don_crissti do you see a dupe to close this with, or would you like to make an Answer?